# Django ckeditor is removing space around <a> tags

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I'm using django-ckeditor with this config:

```
        'enterMode': 2, 
        'forceEnterMode': 'true',
        'basicEntities': 'false',
        
        'fillEmptyBlocks': 'false',
        'tabSpaces': 0,
        'entities': 'false',
```

When the original text look like this:

```
word1 <a>word2</a> word3
```

The final result after saving looks like this:

```
word1<a>word2</a>word3
```

I tried almost all possibilities when it comes to `basicEntities`, `fillEmptyBlocks`, `tabSpaces` and other configurations, but no way, ckeditor is always removing spaces around  tags.

After several trials, I stopped searching for a solution. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this ckeditor github commit](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/pull/10197), this problem was fixed in July 2021. If you are using an older version of ckeditor, you would still see the problem.

Comment: @evergeen I'm using the last version